# Window OnClosing when windows is shutting down

Tags: wpf

In my WPF Main Window I handle the OnClosing event - protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e). This event is also fired when Windows is shutting down, and tries to close the programs opened.
But, when Windows is shutting down, I would like to have a different logic than I would have if the user had clicked on the X button on the top right. Is there a way to distinguish if the window close was initiated by the user and not by the system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Application.SessionEnding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.sessionending.aspx) event to trap shutdown/logoff messages, and put your different logic in there.

Comment: Great! I was able to set a flag in SessionEnding handler, and then used this value in the OnClosing handler. OnClosing happens AFTER SessionEnding.